# What ways can found the description of functions inside DLL?

Tags: function, dll, arguments

I have DLL without documentations and without list of available functions. 
What ways can found the description of functions  inside DLL? I tried to use dllexp.exe, but it showed me only functions names. How I can to get an arguments of functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Microsoft visual studio intellisense  . it shows you each function description(if exist) ,argument(all overrides too) and their types.

Answer (score 2):

Also Dependency Walker should help:

http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [DLL Export Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) or the commercial tool [PE.Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/overview.htm). Both will show you a nice overview and some more information about the library.